# Which of the open-source Bitcoin clients has the most thoroughly commented source code?

Tags: development, open-source, learning

Learning from a source code is very useful at times, but it is a pain if the code is not commented well. Which of the open source Bitcoin software have the most thoroughly and understandably commented source code? That is, if someone wanted to understand how the main client, miner, pool or other Bitcoin software works, which projects should one look at?

Answer (score 5):

I remembered that I had seen answer to that question somewhere, after searching a bit I found it [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/842/how-to-start-programming-your-own-bitcoin-client/850#850).

> Check out BitCoinJ (a from scratch bitcoin implementation in Java) and
> BitCoinSharp (a C# port of BitCoinJ). They are not full
> implementations yet, but they are very far along and can do most of
> the tasks of a bitcoin client.
>
> No matter what language you plan to create your implementation in,
> looking at these is very valuable because they are very thoroughly
> commented and much easier to understand than the official C++ client.

weird, because it's the answer to your other question.

Comment: Well, that mostly covers the main client, but I was inspired to ask this question by trying to find some easy to understand miner code. I was tempted to write about BitCoinJ in the question, but that would be covering just a part of the topic and not adding much to the question.